# Extending dojo after build or run multiple instances

Tags: javascript, api, dojo, arcgis

I have a webapp written in dojo and need to start using the [arcgis Javascript API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/), the problem is this was also writted in dojo.

Is it possible to run multiple instances of dojo on the same page (ie. 1 for my app and 1 for the api)
or Incorporate my custom dijits into the arcgis api (although I can only get a built version)?

If so how?

Answer (score 1):

I read something similar from the dojo tutorial.

I never tried this but it does looks like fit into your need.

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modules_advanced/

Reading the content under title: "Using portable modules" will tell you it is possible load different version of dojo (which means more than 1) in a same page.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Davis gave a talk at the 2014 Esri International Developer's Conference on creating optimized builds of a dojo application that incorporates the Esri API.  A video of his talk will probably be available eventually, but all of his code for doing the build is available on github.

https://github.com/stdavis/dojo-build-presentation
https://github.com/stdavis/dojo-build-example